# How does bigcommerce stencil themes work?

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

Hey I'm a new developer at an ecommerce company and we use bigcommerce platform to build and maintain stores. The problem I am having is understanding the codebase and how all of the files in the theme are interacting with eachother. For example how pages work in relation to templates. Are there any resources to help me understand the inner workings or a bigcommerce theme and how it functions?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great place to start: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjIyMDY5OA-stencil-technology-stack

Comment: Hey Kevin, I second what Nicki mentioned here. Our Dev Center in general will be a great resource for you as you're learning. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/ :)